# package oracle output parameter to a shell variable

Tags: oracle, shell

I need to save the output of the variable to a shell variable

Here the package

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_TESTERR AS

    procedure MAIN (id_out out number) as
       l_id number;
    begin
       l_id := 15; --eg
       id_out := l_id;
    exception when others then
       id_out := - l_id; --negative output
    end main;

 END PKG_TESTERR;
```

So I'm calling sqlplus this way in my shell script:

```
function execPKGSQLPLUS() {
pkg_id_out=$(sqlplus -l -s USERDB/USERPASS@test<<EOF
DECLARE
  id_out_shell NUMBER;
BEGIN
    PKG_TESTERR.SP_MAIN(id_out => id_out_shell)
    END; 
    /  
EOF
)
```

I cannot **enable SERVEROUTPUT ON** on production,
so **I can't use dbms_output printline**..furthermore a lot of PKG I call contains logging procedure that in case serveorutput is turned on, it would slow down the entire execution..

Any idea how can I retrieve the value?

Comment: Out of interest, why can't you enable serveroutput? Is it just a rule _"no serveroutput in production"_?

Comment: As I said, we just enable it in case of debugging, otherwise it's turned off because it could slow down the execution of procedures

Comment: So in theory you could enable it for parts of a script (where you want to return something to a shell script) and disable it for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really can't use `dbms_output` at all, you can use the SQL*Plus [`variable`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve050.htm) and [`print`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve031.htm) commands, passing a client-defined bind variable to the procedure (notice the colon before the variable name in the call):

```
pkg_id_out=$(sqlplus -l -s USERDB/USERPASS@test<<EOF

set pages 0
set feedback off
var id_out_shell NUMBER;

BEGIN
    PKG_TESTERR.MAIN(id_out => :id_out_shell);
END;
/

print id_out_shell

EOF
)
```

If you're only worried about output from within the procedure though, you could turn it on selectively:

```
pkg_id_out=$(sqlplus -l -s USERDB/USERPASS@test<<EOF

set pages 0
set feedback off
set serveroutput on

DECLARE
  id_out_shell NUMBER;
BEGIN
    dbms_output.disable;
    PKG_TESTERR.MAIN(id_out => id_out_shell);
    dbms_output.enable;
    dbms_output.put_line(id_out_shell);
END;
/

EOF
)
```

Comment: [oracle@testdb Example]$ sh test.sh
           -15
-15

Worked like a charme..I've removed the whitespace via bash, but it's ok
I got  what I need, thank you ;)